# why do I need to use useCallback apart from passing it as a prop to memoized component with React.memo

Tags: reactjs

I'm wondering why so many people think that there is a real reason to use useCallback just on its own? Is that a dellussion, or I'm not very smart? The only reason I see is that I will pass it as a prop to the memoized component with React.memo in order to prevent unnecessary rerenders. But why would I need to memoize function itself ? I sometimes hear that it will be performant to do this to not create a function on each render but....

```
useCallback(
// this is function declaration (creation)
()=>{
  console.log('lol');
}
//
,
[]);
```

isn't that a function declaration ?? :) don't we create this function again ? More than that, we still create function on each render but we also invoke useCallback and it decides whether to store new function or keep old one